# how to combine or leave strings in the lists depending on the condition in python?

Tags: python, list

I have three lists:

```
li1 = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b"]
li2 = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "a,", "b", "a", "a"]
li3 = ["b", "b", "a", "a", "b"]
```

I want to "slice and paste" elements by `"b"`

The result is supposed to look like this:

```
li1 = ["aaaa", "b", "b", "aa", "b"]
li2 = ["aaa", "b", "a", "b", "aa"]
li3 = ["b", "b", "aa", "b"]
```

But I don't know how to approach this... please help me!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have some code snippet to show?

Comment: Hello gukwon, see this link : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html and try something using `if` and `for` statements. You can concatenate strings using the `+` operator `'a' + 'a'` returns `aa`. Edit your message to show us your attempts. Good luck !

Comment: @Corentin apart from concatenate it needs to be shifted as well

Comment: @RishiBansal you still can do it with `for`, `+` and `if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

**If you want to join groups *not* belonging to a certain key**

```
from itertools import groupby

def join_except_key(iterable, key='b'):
    groups = groupby(iterable)
    for k, group in groups:
        if k != key:
            yield ''.join(group) # more general: ''.join(map(str, group))
        else:
            yield from group
```

Demo:

```
>>> li1 = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "c", "c"]
>>> list(join_except_key(li1))
['aaaa', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'b', 'cc', 'b', 'cc']
```

**If you want to join groups belonging to a certain key**

```
from itertools import groupby

def join_by_key(iterable, key='a'):
    groups = groupby(iterable)
    for k, group in groups:
        if k == key:
            yield ''.join(group) # more general: ''.join(map(str, group))
        else:
            yield from group
```

Demo:

```
>>> li1 = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "c", "c"]
>>> list(join_by_key(li1))
['aaaa', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

**Details on what `groupby` produces** (non generator approach for `join_except_key`)

```
>>> li1 = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "c", "c"]
>>> groups = [(k, list(group)) for k, group in groupby(li1)]
>>> groups
[('a', ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']),
 ('b', ['b', 'b']),
 ('a', ['a', 'a']),
 ('b', ['b']),
 ('c', ['c', 'c']),
 ('b', ['b']),
 ('c', ['c', 'c'])]
>>>
>>> result = []
>>> for k, group in groups:
...:    if k != 'b':
...:        result.append(''.join(group))
...:    else:
...:        result.extend(group)
...:
>>> result
['aaaa', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'b', 'cc', 'b', 'cc']
```

The list comprehension `groups = [...` in the second line was only needed for inspecting the elements of the grouping operation, it works fine with just `groups = groupby(li1)`.

Comment: its will be better if you add comments about the code, exactly what it is doing.

Comment: what if another element comes in and 'b' is the only one on which we have to split? I guess he asked this only

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), dividing logic into 3 parts:

1. Group by equality to your separator string.
2. Construct an iterable of lists depending on the condition defined in `groupby` key.
3. Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten your iterable of lists.

Here's a demonstration.

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

def sep_by_val(L, k='b'):
    grouper = groupby(L, key=lambda x: x==k)
    gen_of_lst = ([''.join(j)] if not i else list(j) for i, j in grouper)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(gen_of_lst))

sep_by_val(li1)  # ['aaaa', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'b']
sep_by_val(li2)  # ['aaa', 'b', 'a,', 'b', 'aa']
sep_by_val(li3)  # ['b', 'b', 'aa', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

Itertools and Yield from are great python constructs but challenging to master. Something simpler would go like so involving string shifting and splitting.

```
result = []

while len(li1) > 0:
    split = ''.join(li1).partition('b')
    before, part, after = split
    if before:
        result.extend( before.split() )
    if part:
        result.append(part)
    li1 = after.split()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why all the answers look complicated for this. Did I miss something ?

```
li1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
result = []
for e in li1:
    if result and e != 'b' != result[-1]:
        result[-1] += e
    else:
        result.append(e)
print(result)
```

Prints

```
['aaa', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'b']
```

Keep it simple and stupid. Readability matters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I wrote to perform this:

```
def Conbine(Li):
    li=[]
    li.append(Li[0])
    Prev=Li[0]
    for i in Li[1:]:
        if not"b"in(i,Prev):li[-1]+=i
        else:
            Prev=i
            li.append(i)
    return li
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> Conbine(["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b"])

['aaaa', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'b']
>>> Conbine(["a", "a", "a", "b", "a,", "b", "a", "a"])

['aaa', 'b', 'a,', 'b', 'aa']
>>> Conbine(["b", "b", "a", "a", "b"])

['b', 'b', 'aa', 'b']
```

There are a lot of answers here already, but I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but this is another option:

```
def join_in(lst, s):
  res, append = [lst[0]], True
  for i, e in enumerate(lst[1:]):
    if res[-1][0] == s and e == s:
      res[-1] += e
      append = False
    else: append = True
    if append: res.append(e)
  return res
```

Calling on the OP lists:

```
print (join_in(li1, 'a')) #=> ["aaaa", "b", "b", "aa", "b"]
print (join_in(li2, 'a')) #=> ["aaa", "b", "a", "b", "aa"]
print (join_in(li3, 'a')) #=> ["b", "b", "aa", "b"]
```

It is possible to call it on `'b'`:

```
print (join_in(join_in(li3, 'a'), 'b')) #=> ['bb', 'aa', 'b']
```