# how to combine list by condition in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have problem...

I have to lists:

```
li1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
li2 = ["NJE", "NJE", "NJE", "JE", "JE", "NJE", "NJE", "JE"]
```

I want 'li1' to paste by li2's "JE" element... my expectation is:

```
res = ['aaa', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'b']
```

I try like this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648262/8509666):

```
li1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
li2 = ["NJE", "NJE", "NJE", "JE", "JE", "NJE", "NJE", "JE"]
result = []
for e1, e2 in zip(li1, li2):
    if result and e2 != 'JE' != result[-1]:
        result[-1] += e1
    else:
        result.append(e1)
print(result)
```

but result...

```
['aaa', 'b', 'baa', 'b']
```

how to solve this problem? and let me know meaning of if condition:

```
if result and e2 != 'JE' != result[-1]:
```

I don't know double "!=" operation meaning

Comment: operators chaining. e2 != 'JE' and 'JE' != result[-1]

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "list index out of range" error

Comment: It doesn't work because `result` will never have `'JE'` in it, so `'JE' != result[-1]` will always be `True`.

Comment: @Idlehands that crossed my mind, then I forgot :) OP needs to print the values, and possibly store the previous element of the second list. I'm not sure what the logic is there

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes it's quite unclear what exactly OP is going for here.  The original question seems to be related but is quite a departure of what they're trying to do.  I feel like we have an XY problem on hands.

Comment: seeing the thousands of answers below, I guess that it's the case.